# Handling results of eXist-db query made with Python

Tags: python, xquery, exist-db

I have done following code in python to get the response of query in XML stored in eXist-db. I get the value but the problem is type 'instant' as given in the output below. Here's my code:

```
from eulexistdb import db
class TestExist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = db.ExistDB("http://localhost:8899/exist/")   

    def get_res(self,query):
        #result = list()
        res = self.db.executeQuery(query)
        hits = self.db.getHits(res)        
        for i in range(hits):
            print self.db.retrieve(res,i)
            print type(self.db.retrieve(res,i))
xquery = '''
let $x:= doc("/db/sample/books.xml")
return $x/bookstore/book/price/text()'''
a = TestExist()
a.get_res(xquery)
```

Now the query works fine and result too get printed as:

```
30.00
<type 'instance'>
29.99
<type 'instance'>
49.99
<type 'instance'>
39.95
<type 'instance'>
```

What I want is to return the value appended in list 'result'. I tried type conversion but failed. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You state, "I get the value but the problem is ."  Please edit your post to complete this sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's strange - the [docs](http://eulexistdb.readthedocs.org/en/0.17/existdb.html#module-eulexistdb.db) seem to say that the `db.retrieve` function should return a string, but apparently it does not.  In any case, since the print statement gets a useful string out of it, one of these should work:

```
result.append(str(self.db.retrieve(res,i)))
```

or

```
result.append(repr(self.db.retrieve(res,i)))
```

Just uncomment the `#result = list()` line, and add one of the above into the for loop.

Comment: casting to str() worked. So silly I didnt thought of it. I wanted float Value out of it. But the repr() didnt worked as resulted output like ['<xmlrpclib.Binary instance at 0x02258C10>', '<xmlrpclib.Binary instance at 0x02258D50>', '<xmlrpclib.Binary instance at 0x02258198>', '<xmlrpclib.Binary instance at 0x02258620>']

Comment: Great - glad it worked.  If you feel it solved your problem, clicking the "accept" checkmark next to the answer will be helpful for other users to know that it worked.